# C# Serial Port communication

Tags: c#

I'm trying to handle a serial port using the SerialPort class.

The application requires us receive one command first, and then give a reply in 20ms; the problem is, there is a delay(up to 15ms) between the command we read, and the actual command, and we don't have time to send the reply back.

The length of the command we need to read is fixed as 20 bytes, and we poll one byte from the input buffer each time.

```
serialPort.Read(input, 0, 1).
```

I don't know what is wrong with this process.

Answer (score 2):

Why read one byte at a time? If you're expecting 20 bytes, you can write:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
int bytesRead;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = serialPort.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead, buffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) != 0  
    && totalBytesRead < buffer.Length)
{
    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
}
```

At that point, you have all 20 bytes or you've reached the end of the stream.

What do you mean by "there is a delay(up to 15ms) between the command we read, and the actual command,"?

Comment: i will use the scope to check the data on line, when i receive the command, i will send a letter out to compare with the actual command, from scope, i measure the delay as up to 15ms, i want to know what causes this delay.

Comment: You say there's up to 15 ms between when you tell the sender to send a byte, and when the receiver actually reads it? There are any number of things that could cause that. The sender could be buffering briefly, the receiver could be buffering. The receiver might not be able to react *immediately* to the character. Is there a way you can determine when your computer receives the character? 15 ms is pretty suspicious, as that's about the best resolution you'll get out of a .NET program.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the DataRecieved event? I had a similar error some time ago, apparently some of the functionality is not invoked without using the event handler.

Comment: I did not use the DataRecieved event, you mean i should use the DataRecieved event, insteading of polling the data one by one?

Comment: You should definetely use the event, in my case I never actually recieved any data without using the event, it took a couple of days to figure that out.